# Rotating CATransformLayer along anchorpoint

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, calayer, caanimation

Built a cube made of 6 sides: each side is a CALayer which is then each added as a subview to (6) CATransformLayers (to enable 3d transformations). 
these 6 CATransformLayers are added as subviews to a single CATransformLayer.

When rotating this single CATransformLayer that holds the entire cube as one package, everything works, I set the anchorpoint to 0,0 and the anchorpointZ to the middle of the cube: the cube perfectly rotates around its center.

The problem:
I want to 'unfold' the 4 neighboring sides of the current side meaning that the sides on the left, right, above and below rotate 90* towards the user but are still sticking to the side that is facing towards the user.

For that, I for example set the anchorpointZ of the side above the current side to 0 and the anchorpoint to (0.5,1), so that the anchorpoint basically is the middle of the common edge.

Setting up the cube:

```
transformLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];
transformLayer.position = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2);

CGRect layerRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150, 150); //frame rect for cube sides
CGPoint screenCenter = CGPointMake(self.transformLayer.bounds.size.width / 2, self.transformLayer.bounds.size.height / 2);

//side1
side1 = [CALayer layer];
side1.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
side1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
side1.borderWidth = 2.0;
side1.cornerRadius = 30.0;
side1.frame = layerRect;
side1.position = screenCenter;


side1t = [CATransformLayer layer];
[side1t addSublayer:side1];


//side2
side2 = [CALayer layer];
side2.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.25 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
side2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.25 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
side2.borderWidth = 2.0;
side2.cornerRadius = 30.0;    
side2.frame = layerRect;
side2.position = screenCenter;
//positioning
CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
CATransform3D translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(150/2, 0.0, 150/-2 );
CATransform3D position = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, translation);
side2.transform = position;

side2t = [CATransformLayer layer];
[side2t addSublayer:side2];


//side3
side3 = [CALayer layer];
side3.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
side3.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
side3.borderWidth = 2.0;
side3.cornerRadius = 30.0;
side3.frame = layerRect;
side3.position = screenCenter;
//positioning
translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, -150); //150
side3.transform = translation;

side3t = [CATransformLayer layer];
[side3t addSublayer:side3];


//side4
side4 = [CALayer layer];
side4.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.2 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
side4.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.2 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
side4.borderWidth = 2.0;
side4.cornerRadius = 30.0;
side4.frame = layerRect;
side4.position = screenCenter;
//positioning
rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(150/-2, 0.0, 150/-2);
side4.transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, translation);

side4t = [CATransformLayer layer];
[side4t addSublayer:side4];


//side5
side5 = [CALayer layer];
side5.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.8 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
side5.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.8 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
side5.borderWidth = 2.0;
side5.cornerRadius = 30.0;
side5.frame = layerRect;
side5.position = screenCenter;
//positioning
rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, 1.0, .0, 0.0);
translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, 150/-2, 150/-2);
side5.transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, translation);

side5t = [CATransformLayer layer];
[side5t addSublayer:side5];


//side6
side6 = [CALayer layer];
side6.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.0845 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
side6.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.0845 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
side6.borderWidth = 2.0;
side6.cornerRadius = 30.0;
side6.frame = layerRect;
side6.position = screenCenter;
//positioning
rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, 1.0, .0, 0.0);
translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, 150/2, 150/-2);
side6.transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, translation);

side6t = [CATransformLayer layer];
[side6t addSublayer:side6];


[self.transformLayer addSublayer:side1t];
[self.transformLayer addSublayer:side2t];
[self.transformLayer addSublayer:side3t];
[self.transformLayer addSublayer:side4t];
[self.transformLayer addSublayer:side5t];
[self.transformLayer addSublayer:side6t];

self.transformLayer.anchorPointZ = -150/2;
[self.layer addSublayer: transformLayer];
```

This part does not work. The rotation (90°) is correct, but the side ends up in a completely false position, half the cubesize in front of the current side (z-coordinate) and covering half of the front side in the x-y-space, see screenshot

```
-(void)unfoldUpperSide {
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration: 3.0];
side5t.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
side5t.anchorPointZ = 0;
side5t.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI/2, 1, 0, 0);
[CATransaction commit];
}
```

[image: after rotation]

I am stuck on this the whole day, hope someone can help me out..!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a CATransformLayer for each layer, a single CATransformLayer to hold all layers is enough and you can make 3d transforms nevertheless as the CATransformLayer transforms apply on all anchors of the layers in it.

Why your rotation of the individual sides is off is because the anchorPoint of all sides is 0.5,0.5 (that is their respective center, so you rotate around that center)

You can go around this by translating the layer half its size in both desired directions while its being rotated albeit with a slight clipping initially , here is the osx code below, just change the NSColor etc to UIKit counterparts.

[image]

```
-(void)cubeTest{

    float size = 100.0;

    CATransformLayer *transformLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];
    transformLayer.position = CGPointMake(cubeView.bounds.size.width/2,cubeView.bounds.size.height/2);

    CGRect layerRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size, size); //frame rect for cube sides
    CGPoint screenCenter = CGPointMake(transformLayer.bounds.size.width / 2, transformLayer.bounds.size.height / 2);

    //side1
    CALayer *side1 = [CALayer layer];
    side1.borderColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    side1.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.6 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
    side1.borderWidth = 2.0;
    side1.cornerRadius = 30.0;
    side1.frame = layerRect;
    side1.position = screenCenter;
    [transformLayer addSublayer:side1];

    //side2
    CALayer *side2 = [CALayer layer];
    side2.borderColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.25 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    side2.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.25 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
    side2.borderWidth = 2.0;
    side2.cornerRadius = 30.0;
    side2.frame = layerRect;
    side2.position = screenCenter;
    //positioning
    CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    CATransform3D translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(size/2, 0.0, size/-2 );
    CATransform3D position = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, translation);
    side2.transform = position;
    [transformLayer addSublayer:side2];

    //side3
    CALayer *side3 = [CALayer layer];
    side3.borderColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    side3.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.0 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
    side3.borderWidth = 2.0;
    side3.cornerRadius = 30.0;
    side3.frame = layerRect;
    side3.position = screenCenter;
    //positioning
    translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, -size); //size
    side3.transform = translation;
    [transformLayer addSublayer:side3];

    //side4
    CALayer *side4 = [CALayer layer];
    side4.borderColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.2 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    side4.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.2 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
    side4.borderWidth = 2.0;
    side4.cornerRadius = 30.0;
    side4.frame = layerRect;
    side4.position = screenCenter;
    //positioning
    rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(size/-2, 0.0, size/-2);
    side4.transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, translation);
    [transformLayer addSublayer:side4];

    //side5
    CALayer *side5 = [CALayer layer];
    side5.borderColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.8 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    side5.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.8 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
    side5.borderWidth = 2.0;
    side5.cornerRadius = 30.0;
    side5.frame = layerRect;
    side5.position = screenCenter;
    //positioning
    rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, 1.0, .0, 0.0);
    translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, size/-2, size/-2);
    side5.transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, translation);
    [transformLayer addSublayer:side5];

    //side6
    CALayer *side6 = [CALayer layer];
    side6.borderColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.0845 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    side6.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithHue:0.0845 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
    side6.borderWidth = 2.0;
    side6.cornerRadius = 30.0;
    side6.frame = layerRect;
    side6.position = screenCenter;
    //positioning
    rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, 1.0, .0, 0.0);
    translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, size/2, size/-2);
    side6.transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, translation);
    [transformLayer addSublayer:side6];

    transformLayer.anchorPointZ = -size/2;
    [cubeView setWantsLayer:YES];
    [cubeView.layer addSublayer:transformLayer];

    //animate

    CGFloat perspective = -1.0/10000.0;
    CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = perspective;
    transformAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];

    transform.m34 = perspective;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) , 1, 0, 0);

    transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];

    transformAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    transformAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    transformAnimation.duration = 10.0;
    [transformLayer addAnimation:transformAnimation forKey:@"RotateTheBox"];

    [self sideAnimation:side1 transform:CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DRotate(side1.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) , 1, 0, 0), 0, size/2, size/2)];
    [self sideAnimation:side3 transform:CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DRotate(side3.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90) , 1, 0, 0), 0, size/2, -size/2)];
    [self sideAnimation:side2 transform:CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DRotate(side2.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) , 1, 0, 0), 0, size/2, size/2)];
    [self sideAnimation:side4 transform:CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DRotate(side4.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90) , 1, 0, 0), 0, size/2, -size/2)];
    [self sideAnimation:side6 transform:CATransform3DTranslate(side6.transform, 0, 0, size)];//lower cap

}

-(void)sideAnimation:(CALayer*)side transform:(CATransform3D)transform
{
    CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
    transformAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    transformAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    transformAnimation.duration = 10.0;
    [side addAnimation:transformAnimation forKey:@"rotateSide"];
}
```